# Is there a way to put multiple matrix in one row with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

sympy could output the result in Latex

for instance,

```
A = Matrix(((1,1),(2,2),(0,0)))
A
```

outputs

[image]

```
A.T
```

outputs

[image]

is there a way to put multiple matrix in one row with sympy?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want but does this work for you?

```
In [17]: A = Matrix(((1,1),(2,2),(0,0)))                                                                                                                         

In [18]: MatMul(A, A.T, evaluate=False)                                                                                           
Out[18]: 
⎡1  1⎤          
⎢    ⎥ ⎡1  2  0⎤
⎢2  2⎥⋅⎢       ⎥
⎢    ⎥ ⎣1  2  0⎦
⎣0  0⎦
```